# Linked viewlist/list removing selected items

Tags: c#, list, listview

I am a little unclear in the following so to clear things up my ultimate goal is to create a button to remove a value displayed in a listview, the value is a list item.

This is the sort of thing I want...

```
studentList.Remove(listView1.SelectedIndices);
refreshList();
```

of course if that worked I would be in heaven, but it throws errors of course...

The list is `private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()` it is generated from another windows form.

I am having a problem removing items from a list/viewlist I am using.

Here is the code that keeps throwing the errors:

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // studentList.RemoveAt(listBoxStudent.SelectedIndex);

    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        studentList.RemoveAt(listView1.Items[i].Selected));
        i--;
    }
    refreshList();
}
```

The values are being put into the listview properly but I cannot seem to find a way to delete the values from the listview and the list together (`refreshlist()` clears and repopulates the listview according to the list `studentList`)

```
private void refreshList()
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Student stu in studentList)
    {
        string[] filler = new string[5];
        filler[0] = stu.Name.ToString();
        filler[1] = stu.Residency.ToString();
        filler[2] = stu.Credits.ToString();
        filler[3] = stu.Tuition.ToString();

        listView1.Items.Add(stu.Id.ToString()).SubItems.AddRange(filler);

        listView1.View = View.Details;
    }
}
```

edit: added `refreshlist()` as requested.

Comment: Can you add your refreshlist() code?  Also, why use a for loop to remove an item?  Especially since in your loop you are negating your i variable so it doesn't change?

Comment: added the refreshlist(), I am really not sure what the best method is to remove the items, however with it being a listview it can have multiple items selected so it was my understanding that a loop would be required. Still new to the language.

Comment: what is your goal with that first loop that contains `studentList.RemoveAt(..)` - do you just want to remove the selected item? If so, why the loop?

Comment: I just want to remove the selected item I am unsure how to target the selected indexes in listview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,

Dude, just remove the **object** from the list (forget RemoveAt(index)), then refresh the View... it will (or atleast it *should*) pickup the changes from "the model" (i.e. the students-list).

List.Remove Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx

Cheers. Keith.

Comment: The problem is removing the item from the list at the selected index... it is throwing errors when I try to select the index.

Comment: figured it out your answer is the most relevant.

Answer (score 2):

try changing your loop to

```
            for(int i = studentList.Items.Count -1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                if(studentList.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    studentList.Items[i].Remove();
            }
```

or in another way

```
            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in studentList.Items)
            {
                if (lvi.Selected == true)
                    lvi.Remove();
            }
```

Comment: +1 Inverting the loop is a neat way around the skip-an-index problem.

Comment: Will removing the ListViewItem remove the Student from the underlying studentsList? Yes: That's a question. Obviously I suspect that it's not GOOD news, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: maybe Im not being clear enough in my question :( I am trying to remove from studentList at the selected items in the listView. I am not trying to remove the item from the listView because that would just repopulate on the refreshlist() call.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't generally try to manipulate both. Modify the underlying datasource (in your case, studentList), then update the ListView. If you modify your studentList to use an `ObservableCollection`, it will actually update the UI for you.

Also, if your collection's data type supports `IComparable`, you should just be able to use listView1.Remove(), rather than RemoveAt().

Comment: How do I remove at the listView selected item though? Refreshlist will handle the listView I just need to know how to target the selected item for removal in the StudentList...

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the collection that you are trying to iterate through. Once you have deleted the first item you have changed the list so the for loop will give you an error. The example given that iterates backwards (i--) is one way to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean the explenation of why you are getting the error didn't help or iterating backwards through the collection didn't help?

Comment: iterating backwords through the collection. I have got it working now though thank you.